# Created a sub or nested channel/pipeline in Netty?

Tags: netty

In Netty 4.1, is it possible to create a sub or nested channel/pipeline?

E.g., I have a pipeline that has various codecs installed to it for a protocol/serialization.  At the end of the pipeline, I hand off a message to my application level logic.  Over-simplified example:

```
@Override
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Request request) throws Exception {
    try {
        Response response = applicationLogic.handle(request);
        ctx.writeAndFlush(response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e);
    }
}
```

This applicationLogic's handle method can then do any sequential logic it wants.  This cleanly separates my application level logic, however, I want to take advantage of the "[advanced form of the Intercepting Filter pattern](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html)" that Netty's ChannelPipeline offers.  I want to expose a Pipeline to my application level so that users may easily add codecs, event listeners, uncaught exception handlers, etc.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to create some type of nested ChannelPipeline, where its head/tail will propagate into the outer pipeline.  E.g.,

```
A - > B -> { X -> Y -> Z } -> C
```

Where I can expose the `{ X -> Y -> Z }` pipeline to my application layer and not be concerned with mutations affecting the pipeline I control.

Is there any clean way to simulate this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

No need for it, Netty does not support nested pipelines. That said you can modify the ChannelPipeline on the fly and put the needed ChannelHandlers in there (and remove the old ones)